# Syscalls for x86-64 Linux NASM(YASM) detailed description

Tags: linux, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I found the list of syscalls for x86-64 mode (with arguments):
http://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/
but where can I get detailed description of this syscalls?

For example below, which flags can be used for 'open' syscall except 0102o (rw, create), in other cases:
read only, write only, etc.

```
SECTION .data
    message: db 'Hello, world!',0x0a    
    length:    equ    $-message        
    fname    db "result"
    fd       dq 0

SECTION .text
global _start   
_start:
        mov rax, 2            ; 'open' syscall
        mov rdi, fname        ; file name
        mov rsi, 0102o        ; read and write mode, create if not
        mov rdx, 0666o        ; permissions set
        syscall

        mov [fd], rax

        mov    rax, 1          ; 'write' syscall
        mov    rdi, [fd]       ; file descriptor
        mov    rsi, message    ; message address
        mov    rdx, length     ; message string length
        syscall

        mov rax, 3             ; 'close' syscall
        mov rdi, [fd]          ; file descriptor  
        syscall 

        mov    rax, 60        
        mov    rdi, 0        
        syscall
```

Based on source (may be)
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c
how to understand it, which (list of all for open) flags can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the syscalls is in section 2 of the man pages and/or in the comments in the source code.

The man page begins with:

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>

   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

> The argument *flags* must include one of the following access modes: **O_RDONLY**,  **O_WRONLY**, or **O_RDWR**.  These request opening the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.
>
> In addition, zero or more file creation flags and file status flags can be bitwise-or'd in *flags*.  The file creation flags are **O_CREAT**, **O_EXCL**, **O_NOCTTY**, and **O_TRUNC**.

The values for these are trivially looked up in the system header files.

Comment: grep -i 0102 /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h    -nothing. How to take?

Comment: @Alex0102o:  I don't understand.  That file is a list of the syscall entry numbers:  nothing to do with a *flags* argument.  The flags are in `/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h` where 0102 is clearly `O_RDWR | O_CREAT` (at least in Fedora 17-64).

Comment: wallyk, yes in /usr/include/bits/fcntl.h are this (Debian Lenny 64bit) Thanks you! (Sorry my bad english) 0102 I took from 32bit nasm.

Comment: @Alex0102o:  You are welcome.  Please be sure to "accept" my answer by clicking on the checkmark beside my answer.  When you have enough reputation, you can also upvote good answers (and downvote bad ones).

Comment: @wallyk #include is about c, not asm. Is there a way in nasm to include those symbols? Other answers in SO also say "use names, not numbers", but of course nasm does not recognise O_RDONLY.

Comment: @flaschenpost:  One way is to look at the include files and use the numeric constants in asm, though that isn't "excellent" technique for widely-used constants.  Nasm does have an [include facility](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html) (see 2.1.16 and 2.1.17) which could be used to include a file containing useful constants.  I doubt it will work with the C files (but it just might), so at worst, you might have to make your own include files for Nasm use.